# nlog to log to specific methods

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using nlog to write logs to file. Currently when i log something then it logs everything from that class. I want to for example only log things which are failing in specific methods

```
public void myMethod(){
        try
        {
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("testing");
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Sample informational message");
        }
}
```

Comment: "Currently when i log something then it logs everything from that class" what you mean ? Would you provide an example please ? What does it log that you don't expect ?

Comment: @Rainman i meant to say it logs all methods executed in whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use `GetLogger` instead of `GetCurrentClassLogger`

```
Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("myLogger");
```

In the config you could route/filter on the logger name:

```
<rule name="myLogger" minLevel="trace" writeTo="myFile"  />
```

Comment: where is reference to myLogger?

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to capture the name of the class-method that is doing the logging (and not just the class-name).

This is called callsite in NLog (Can provide class-name, member-function-name , source-file and linenumber at callsite):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer

Activating the feature gives a huge overhead (Will capture full StackTrace for each log-event), so be careful when enabling it (But calling GetCurrentClassLogger() for every log-event is just as expensive).

Alternative you could capture the information yourself, by wrapping NLog-Logger and using the Caller Information Attributes (Much better performance):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information